# Module not found error- Pandas module not found

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io.spss'
It is showing when I am trying to import pandas as pd. Can anyone help me out to figure out this.

Comment: You might have to delete and install pandas again. There might be a problem with the installation. Also try to install a different version.

Comment: Can you recommend which version?

Comment: Something like 1.3.2 or 1.2.5? Just something older or newer than what you have installed

Comment: Is this the code to do this in anaconda prompt- pip install pandas 1.3.2?

Comment: pip install pandas==1.3.2

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually I re-installed the anaconda package. And now its resolved. Again thank you so much.

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu in Anaconda it's `conda install pandas==1.3.2`